# Letter after a number, what is it called?

Tags: c#, variables, numbers

What is this called?

```
double  d1 = 0d;
decimal d2 = 0L;
float   d3 = 0f;
```

And where can I find a reference of characters I can use? If I want to cast `0` to `short`, which letter I need?

Comment: Not an official list, but this is useful: http://www.dotnetperls.com/suffix

Comment: [Numeric Literal](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpNumericLiterals.aspx) I believe is what you're after. And `(short)0` would cast for you.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The best source is the C# specification, specifically section [*Literals*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure#literals).

The relevant bits:

> The type of an integer literal is determined as follows:
>
> - If the literal has no suffix, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`.
> - If the literal is suffixed by U or u, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: `uint`, `ulong`.
> - If the literal is suffixed by L or l, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: `long`, `ulong`.
> - If the literal is suffixed by UL, Ul, uL, ul, LU, Lu, lU, or lu, it is of type `ulong`.
>
> If no *real_type_suffix* is specified, the type of the real literal is `double`. Otherwise, the real type suffix determines the type of the real literal, as follows:
>
> - A real literal suffixed by F or f is of type `float`. […]
> - A real literal suffixed by D or d is of type `double`. […]
> - A real literal suffixed by M or m is of type `decimal`. […]

That means the letter (or letters) is called “suffix”. There is no way to represent `short` this way, so you have to use `(short)0`, or just `short x = 0;`.

Answer (score 18):

It is called a suffix.
An overview can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110111144535/http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/08/secrets-and-lies-of-type-suffixes-in-c-and-vb-net)

Answer (score 10):

This

```
double  d1 = 0d;
```

is an example of a literal and the character after the digits is a suffix. There is not one for `short`. You need to cast:

```
short s = (short)0;
```

These are defined in 2.4.4 of the language specification, specifically 2.4.4.2 will tell you about integer literals where you will see that there is no way to express a `short` using a literal. Additionally, the `integer-type-suffix`es are:

```
U  u  L  l  UL  Ul  uL  ul  LU  Lu  lU  lu
```

which represent various signed/unsigned int/long types. Again, no way to express a `short` using literal.

Comment: -1: They are not called literals. They are called suffixes. The literal is the complete number including the suffix.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: Clearly he just wants to express a `short` using a literal, and therefore I explained the larger concept. Thank you for explaining, at least.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a reference to the literals at the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664672(v=VS.71).aspx

Only the letter after the number is called a suffix.

There is not one specifically for short.

And these are only value literals so that you can differ the different types of values. When you cast you use the regular casting methods.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the reference of the decimal type in C#:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75(v=VS.100).aspx

And here's the reference of the "Standard Numeric Format Strings", which is what you are asking about:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Comment: Seems like I misunderstood the question