# Meaning of 1U in C# and OPEN XML SDK 2.0

Tags: c#, excel, openxml-sdk

I always see the 1U code in C# especially in styles in OPEN XML SDK 2.0. Does anybody know the meaning of it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Letter after a number, what is it called?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681112/letter-after-a-number-what-is-it-called)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an `unsigned literal`.

For example, if you do:

```
var u = 1U;
Console.Write(u.GetType());
```

It'll tell you that it's a `System.UInt32`.

See [the C# spec](http://www.jaggersoft.com/csharp_standard/9.4.4.2.htm#integer-literal) for details.

Answer (score 1):

The `U` means the number is an *unsigned* constant.

Comment: Hi, Where did you found this buddy :) +1 for the help

Comment: I'm certain the C# language documentation explains this in the section on numeric literals.

Answer (score 1):

It specifies that you have an [unsigned int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0sksh43.aspx) of value 1.

Comment: Can u give me more examples here dude :) +1 for u

Comment: @AllanChua I think you mean +14U