# How does the binary representation of a C# ulong data type work?

Tags: c#, binary, long-integer, bitboard, ulong

I'm currently trying to print a `ulong` data type as 8x8 grid of binary bits since the `ulong` data type has 8 bytes - 64 bits. While trying to do so, I keep getting a bit turned on with 32-bit offset. To understand my problem, look at the following.

When I print the bits, I would like for it to be formatted this way.

```
8 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
7 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
6 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
4 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
3 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    - - - - - - - -
    a b c d e f g h

    Decimal: 0
    Hexadecimal: 0
```

These are the two relevant methods used to print the bits in that way.

```cs
public static bool getBit(ulong board, int index) => (board & (1u << (index))) > 0;

public static void printBoard(ulong board)
    {
        for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            Console.Write($"{i + 1} |");
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(" {0}", getBit(board, (i * 8) + j) ? 1 : 0);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("    - - - - - - - -\n    a b c d e f g h\n");
        Console.WriteLine($"    Decimal: {board}\n    Hexadecimal: {board:X}\n");
    }
```

Using these methods, when I run the program, I get this 8x8 grid for the following code.

```cs
ulong a = 0b10;
printBoard(a);
```

```
8 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
7 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
6 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5 | 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
4 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
3 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 | 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 | 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
    - - - - - - - -
    a b c d e f g h

    Decimal: 2
    Hexadecimal: 2
```

Although *decimal* and *hexadecimal* formats indicate that I have 2 as the number stored in `a`, the 8x8 grid doesn't. Why is the bit on *b5* or the 34th bit(counting from the bottom) turned on? When the 34th bit is turned on, the value of the variable `a` changes to a very high number in place of `2`.

Is there something I need to understand about the underlying implementation of the `ulong` data type or is there something wrong with what I'm doing?

Any advice or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find the answer here: [what is 1u?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982690/meaning-of-1u-in-c-sharp-and-open-xml-sdk-2-0#:%7E:text=The%20U%20means%20the%20number%20is%20an%20unsigned%20constant.)
The answer is an int32 and not an int64 as you expected.

You just have to replace 1u by 1ul in your getBit method.