# C# Method Name Expected Error

Tags: c#, methods, console

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DebtCalculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double creditcardbalance;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter in credit card balance:");
            creditcardbalance = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            double monthlypayementamount;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter in the monthly payement amount:");
            monthlypayementamount = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            double percentagerate;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter in annual percentage rate:");
            percentagerate = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            int payoff;
            double dailyinterestrate;
            dailyinterestrate = percentagerate / 365;
            payoff = -(1 / 30) * Math.Log(1 + creditcardbalance / monthlypayementamount (1 - (1 + dailyinterestrate), Math.Pow(0, 30))) / Math.Log(1 + dailyinterestrate);
        }

    }
}
```

the "payoff = -(1 / 30) * Math.Log(1 + creditcardbalance / monthlypayementamount " where it says monthlypayementamount it returns an error of "method name expected" how do i resolve?

Comment: `monthlypayementamount **PutSomeOperatorHere** (`

Comment: Based on your code, you are trying to use `monthlypayementamount` like it is a method, but it is a variable. What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: trying to divide credit card balance by monthly payment amount

Comment: @tleng1 please explain the whole `payoff`. how is it calculated? i flaged your question as off-topic because its a simple error. besides its unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Im trying to calculate the amount of time it will take to pay off debt . I am following a the formula "Credit card equation"

Comment: sorry i still dont know the formula. anyway.your problem is the part `monthlypayementamount (1 - (1 + dailyinterestrate)`. right after you wrote `monthlypayementamount`. do you want to multiply it by `(1 - (1 + dailyinterestrate)`?

Comment: the formula is on http://www.businessinsider.com/11-personal-finance-equations-you-need-to-know-2012-7?op=1 its at the bottom .. credit card equation.

Comment: where it says 1+b/p is where my 1 + creditcardbalance / monthlypayementamount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the formula your equation should be like this.

```
payoff = -(1d / 30) * Math.Log(1 + creditcardbalance / monthlypayementamount * (1 - Math.Pow(1 + dailyinterestrate, 30))) / Math.Log(1 + dailyinterestrate);
```

Your problems. in mathematics `p(2)` may translate to `p*(2)` but in coding you have to write everything `p*(2)`.

And the part `Math.Pow(0,30)` evaluates to `0^30`. you have to put `1 + dailyinterestrate` (according to formula) instead of 0.

Also the result of this equation is type of double. but `payoff` as i see now is type of `int`. change the type of payoff to double or cast the result to int.

The other problem is `-(1/30)`. they are both `integer` means the result is without decimal. so put `d` after the number so it will be type of double which holds decimal part. thanks to @A.S.H

You must Write the result in the console with `Console.WriteLine()` method

your code should look like this.

```
double payoff;
double dailyinterestrate;
dailyinterestrate = percentagerate / 365;
payoff = -(1d / 30) * Math.Log(1 + creditcardbalance / monthlypayementamount * (1 - Math.Pow(1 + dailyinterestrate, 30))) / Math.Log(1 + dailyinterestrate);

Console.WriteLine(payoff);
```

Comment: it runs but does not show to output of how many months it takes.. theres no results that show??

Comment: (1/30) is zero, or did I miss something?

Comment: @A.S.H oh. well... i missed it

Comment: nvm fixed it awesome ty m.kazem

Comment: one more question can you explain why the (1d / 30 ) why add d and what does it represent?

Comment: `int` in c# is the type that stores only whole numbers. it means you cant store `1.345` inside `int`. when you divide `1/30`  both numbers are type of `integer`. the result is `0.0333` but because `int` cannot hold decimal part the result will be only the whole part which is  `0` now.with `d` suffix now the number `1d` is type of double. means it can hold `0.0333`.i suggest you read a tutorial about number types. also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681112/letter-after-a-number-what-is-it-called @tleng1

Comment: and why numbers without suffix  (like in `1/30`) is not type of double is because how it is designed. the default type is integer by the compiler. @tleng1

Comment: that was clear , i understand . thanks for all your help.