# What is the letter after a double declaration in Csharp?

Tags: c#, double

For example:

```
private const double MAX_BATTERIJ = 100D, MIN_BATTERIJ = 0D;
```

What is the D here? I've also seen an m but have no clue what it does.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types - 
The literal without suffix or with the d or D suffix is of type double
The literal with the f or F suffix is of type float
The literal with the m or M suffix is of type decimal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Letter after a number, what is it called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681112/letter-after-a-number-what-is-it-called) The exact duplicate

Answer (score 5):

**Real literals**
The type of a real literal is determined by its suffix - [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types)

```
decimal x = 20M;  //decimal
double x = 20D;   //double
float x = 3.3F;   //float
```

site note - there are also **Integer literals** [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types)

```
long x = 20L;     //long   
uint x = 2U;      //Unsigned Int
ulong x = 2UL;    //Unsigned Long
double x = 2.1E2; //exponent (210)
int x = 0xCA;     //hex
```

Answer (score 0):

It indicates that the value is a `double`.

You can use `f` or `F` for `float`, `d` or `D` for `double` and `m` or `M` for `decimal`.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types#real-literals) for more information on floating point suffixes.

Answer (score 0):

It is the language reserved type indicator, indicating what type the literal number should be interpreted to.
A way to understand this is looking at some code:

```
var x = 20D;
Console.WriteLine(x.GetType()); // Will write System.Double
var y = 20M;
Console.WriteLine(y.GetType()); // Will write System.Decimal
```

Here it is obvious that the compiler casts the literal type of the number 20 using the type indicator to the matching var type. Without the suffix it would not know which type of variable to create the "var" as. It could be an int, a decimal, a double and so on.
Without you might later use is against another type and experience a type/cast exception trying to use as the wrong type.

Hope this way of seeing it helps clarify the use.

There is also a great tutorial on the subject here https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/data-type-suffixes-in-c-sharp/